# How to detect the scroll panel is still scrolling or not in GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I need checkpoint to detect the scrollpanel is still scrolling or not. I am sending the server request while scrolling the scroll bar with the delay of 100 milliseconds.
I meant, every 100 milliseconds i am sending the request to server while scrolling. This is fine when i do scroll slowly in the grid. But, when I drag from page top to bottom
I could see there are multiple request is going to server. I want to know is there any flag to delete the long scroll. Please find the code

```
    @Override
    public void onScroll(final ScrollEvent scrollEvent)
    {
        int delay = 100;
        super.onScroll(scrollEvent, delay);
    }
```

I am using GWT class com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.ScrollEvent. I need below kind of logic

```
    @Override
    public void onScroll(final ScrollEvent scrollEvent)
    {
        int delay = 100;
        if(stillScollbarScrolling) {
            return;
        } else {
            super.onScroll(scrollEvent, delay);
        }           
    }
```

So, I need to consider last request only as valid request. All the previous requests are invalid. I have logic to cancel all the previous logic. But, I need check point to still scroll bar is scrolling without release the bar.

Please help me..

Comment: So you need only the last request for long scroll?

Comment: Yes Adam.  Otherwise, too many request is going to hit the server database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you need to cancel repeating scroll events. If so, you can use a `Timer` to do that.

Once a scroll event occurs you start a timer. If next scroll event is fired you check if a timer is still running. If so, it means that you have a repeating event that should be cancelled. If a timer is not running than it is not a repeating event and a request should be done.

Here is the code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do nothing...
    }
};

@Override
public void onScroll(final ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
    if(timer.isRunning()) {
        // timer is running - stop the timer and do nothing (cancel event)
        timer.cancel();
    }
    else
        // timer is not running - do request
        super.onScroll(scrollEvent);

    // restart the timer with 100ms delay
    timer.schedule(100);
}
```

Please, notice that the first scroll event will cause doing the request because the timer is not started yet.

Comment: I tried this way, but every 100ms request is going to server when I do the slow scrolling(Still scrolling). My case is little different I agree your point. I am still scrolling with some delay(lets say 110 ms). In this case, i want to capture only last scroll position to send the request..